# Ruby daemon with clean shutdown

Tags: ruby, daemon

I would like to make a ruby daemon that would gracefully shutdown with a kill command.
I would like to add a signal trap that would wait until `#code that could take some time to run` finishes before shutting down.  How would I add that to something like this:

```
pid = fork do
   pid_file = "/tmp/pids/daemon6.pid"
   File.open(pid, 'w'){ |f| f.write(Process.pid) }
   loop do
      begin
         #code that could take some time to run
      rescue Exception => e
         Notifier.deliver_daemon_rescued_notification(e)
      end
      sleep(10)
   end
end
Process.detach pid
```

Also, would it be better to have that in a separate script, like a separate kill script instead of having it as part of the daemon code?  Like something `monit` or `God` would call to stop it?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can catch `Interrupt`, like this:

```
pid = fork do
  begin
    loop do
      # do your thing
      sleep(10)
    end
  rescue Interrupt => e
    # clean up
  end
end
Process.detach(pid)
```

You can do the same with `Signal.trap('INT') { ... }`, but with `sleep` involved I think it's easier to catch an exception.

*Update:* this is a more traditional way of doing it, and it makes sure the loop always finishes a complete go before it stops:

```
pid = fork do
  stop = false
  Signal.trap('INT') { stop = true }
  until stop
    # do your thing
    sleep(10)
  end
end
```

The downside is that it will always do the `sleep`, so there will almost always be a delay until the process stops after you've killed it. You can probably get around that by sleeping in bursts, or doing a combination of the variants (rescuing the `Interrupt` just around the `sleep` or something).

Comment: Thanks for your reply theo, the problem is that catching Interrupt won't let the main loop to finish.  What I would like to do is to catch the interrupt, let the loop finish if it started and then clean up and kill the process.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way of doing it that exits more gracefully (but has problems with `sleep` instead).

Comment: That will do nicely.  Thank you!  What if sleep call was taken out of the until loop?  I thought that ruby's sleep was already in bursts so that INT signal should kick it out of sleep.  Anyways, extra sleep is a much smaller problem then a halt to a process in the middle of the loop.

Comment: guard sleep with if !stop, so if it the interrupt comes while you are working it won't go to sleep at all and stop the loop immediately. What remains then is interrupting while in sleep - I don't know if it then breaks out of sleep.